# What are these copy to app buttons called in swift?

Tags: ios

What do you call these copy to app buttons and how to implement them with your own app? Copy to Spark, Viber etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are action / share  extensions exposed by other applications to handle a text / photo / url  share from any app , you can find them under File->New->Target

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That view is a UIActivityViewController.

Those buttons are activities.

The controller is created and then the information is passed in. The activities shown are determined by the type of info passed in (photos, text, url, etc...) and the apps that have registered to handle that type of info.

Have a google for UIActivityViewController to see how you can implement those activities for your own app.